# pop up to replace variables and run *.cmd file

Tags: cmd

I have 2 variables: @@PWD@@ and @@DATABASE@@ that I need to replace in a *.cmd script.

When running the *.cmd script I would like to have a 2 pop up to request: "please enter the password" and another one for the database: "please enter your database".

Once I have the pwd and database entered I would need my *.cmd file to have the variable @@PWD@@ and @@DATABASE@@ replaced by the input entered and be run.

I am not sure about the correct way tpo to that! I tried the >SET PWD=TESTPWD but I would like to know whether you would already have a script that could help me out?

Many thanks,
Graig

Answer (score 1):

to ask for a new value, use `set /p "PWD=Enter the password: "`